# Failed to Run ReactNative App after converting expo app into react-native

Tags: expo, react-native

This is mentioned that firstly I have created a react-native application using `expo init ProjectName` and it's run on my device what I wanted. But I am failed to make an APK file from this react native app (`expo init ProjectName`). This is why I wanna to create a react native using `npx react-native init ProjectName` and copy all the source code, app.js, package.json, and assets. After moving all the files I have used `npm install --force` because it's failed to install when I have used `npm install`. And then I have faced the error to run this code and the error is given bellow,

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1839 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
WARNING:: Please remove usages of `jcenter()` Maven repository from your build scripts and migrate your build to other Maven repositories.
This repository is deprecated and it will be shut down in the future.
See http://developer.android.com/r/tools/jcenter-end-of-service for more information.
Currently detected usages in: project ':react-native-picker_picker', project ':react-native-safe-area-context', project ':react-native-screens'

> Task :react-native-community_datetimepicker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
66 actionable tasks: 61 executed, 5 up-to-date
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
D:\ReactNative\CovidVisa\node_modules\@react-native-community\datetimepicker\android\src\main\java\com\reactcommunity\rndatetimepicker\RNDatePickerDialogModule.java:23: error: package com.facebook.react.modul
e.annotations does not exist
import com.facebook.react.module.annotations.ReactModule;
                                            ^
D:\ReactNative\CovidVisa\node_modules\@react-native-community\datetimepicker\android\src\main\java\com\reactcommunity\rndatetimepicker\RNDatePickerDialogModule.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
@ReactModule(name = RNDatePickerDialogModule.FRAGMENT_TAG)
 ^
  symbol: class ReactModule
D:\ReactNative\CovidVisa\node_modules\@react-native-community\datetimepicker\android\src\main\java\com\reactcommunity\rndatetimepicker\RNTimePickerDialogModule.java:13: error: package com.facebook.react.modul
e.annotations does not exist
D:\ReactNative\CovidVisa\node_modules\@react-native-community\datetimepicker\android\src\main\java\com\reactcommunity\rndatetimepicker\RNDateTimePickerPackage.java:12: error: com.reactcommunity.rndatetimepick
er.RNDateTimePickerPackage is not abstract and does not override abstract method createJSModules() in com.facebook.react.ReactPackage
public class RNDateTimePickerPackage implements ReactPackage {
       ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
5 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_datetimepicker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
```

**Note:** The error is also given on the attached file, please concern about that. Advanced Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `./gradlew clean` and delete your node_modules folder?

Comment: I have deleted node_modules folder. But It's not solved

Comment: I can remember I definitely had same issue some time ago …

Do you run `npm install --save-dev jetifier` and
`npx jetify`

Comment: I have used just `npm install --force`

Comment: @MichaelBahl Can you know me one thing ? I have used `expo-constants` package in `expo init ProjectsName` and Now is it possible to support this expo command  in `npx react-native init ProjectsName app?`

Comment: Yes, you can use expo modules in an app created with `native init ProjectsName app?` 
How to setup  react-native-unimodules  https://docs.expo.dev/bare/hello-world/?redirected.